# Gráficos no Android

Tags: android, google-charts

Preciso implementar um gráfico de barras em um app Android. Alguém conseguiria me ajudar? Encontrei somente o google-chart mas não entendi como aplicar ao app.

Comment: fiz uma pequena busca no google e encontrei outras opções com tutoriais
http://www.achartengine.org/
http://www.infragistics.com/products/android
http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/07/chart-and-graph-library-for-android.html

http://www.java4less.com/charts/chart.php?info=android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pra você usar o Google-chart no Android, você precisa trabalhar encima de uma **Webview**

[Aqui tem um slideshare](http://pt.slideshare.net/ecgreb/google-charts-for-android) bacana utilizando o Google-chart junto com [este exemplo](https://github.com/ecgreb/hello-pizza-chart)

Se você não quiser utilizar através de uma Webview, tenta usar o aChartEngine:

[Nesse link com o source](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) e um exemplo [nesse post](http://jaxenter.com/effort-free-graphs-on-android-with-achartengine-46199.html)

Comment: Muito  obrigado cara.....ajudou muito...estou iniciando no android... ficou show de bola...